# Handle signed out state with WorkManager with dagger injection

Tags: android, dagger-2, android-workmanager

I have a pretty complicated dependency scenario. Currently I inject (indirectly) my database into a Worker via constructor injection. However when the user is logged out, getting a database will throw an exception, because the user id is required to access it. I see a few options:

1. Provide the database as nullable.
2. Cancel all Work when logging out (could be easily forgotten).
3. Lazily inject (must be field injection?) the database after first checking for auth inside the worker.

Option one isn't really an option because then it seems like I would have to make a large chunk of my dependency graph nullable.

Any recommendations or has anyone solved this before in a better way?

Comment: You can do option 3 and keep construction injection, with Dagger instead of having a constructor parameter of type `YourDatabase`, have one of type `Provider<YourDatabase>` or alternatively `Lazy<YourDatabase>`, more info here: https://dagger.dev/api/latest/dagger/Lazy.html

Comment: Thanks yeah that's exactly what I did. `Lazy` seems to be the best fit.